# How to create an email viewer like the iPad native email viewer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

The native email reader on the iPad has a header region (containing the From, To, Subject line, attachments etc.) and a region below the header that displays the email body.  When you pinch-zoom on the body, the body panel becomes larger without also increasing the size of the header region.

I've been tasked with reproducing this viewer in our own email client application, but this is proving extremely difficult to get working correctly.  Basically, I have an outer `UIScrollView` full-screen, which contains (as contents) a `UIView` for the header and a `UIWebView` for the body.  This works, sort of, but it ends up not behaving quite like the native.  The Apple documentation says that you should never put a `UIWebView` on a `UIScrollView`, since iOS will get confused about which view is supposed to respond to touch events and gestures (this is true - iOS *does* get confused about this).

Any ideas?

Comment: I need to do the same thing on the iPhone. Did you find an answer to this? Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Have you tried using a tableview? - I saw a tutorial somewhere on this